# Need to save video captured from webcam in flash. What`s my next step?

Tags: flash

Im making a flash app that will capture video from the users web-cam, show whats being captured and when he clicks submit, send this to the server.

Its already capturing video from the user web cam, but its not recording anywhere. Whats my next step to save it somewhere where it can be played to the user after recorded and after he clicks in  a `submit` button send it to the server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Red5](https://code.google.com/p/red5/) It's an open source flash server that can do recording of client streams.  Alternatively [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/), would do it too, but that will cost you.